# What's the use of count() as we already have size for Map, List and Array?

Tags: kotlin, collections

In Kotlin collections (list, array and map), to get the size, we already have `size`. What's the use of `count()`?

```
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
list.size
list.count()

val map = mapOf(1 to 1, 2 to 2, 3 to 3)
map.size
map.count()

val array = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)
array.size
array.count()
```

Essentially, if we check them under the hood, they just return `size`.

Comment: `count` can take a *predicate*: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/count.html

Comment: The `count` with predicate is a different function.

Comment: Just guessing, but they probably added the empty overload for convenience.

Comment: It's a more interesting question than it first seems…  My guess is either for symmetry, to be consistent with the predicate version; or possibly it once had a stronger purpose which library changes have removed, but they need to keep it for compatibility.  There's no clue in the source code, though.

Comment: The `count()` function is necessary for `Iterable`. They do not have a size property and therefor need to be iterated to get the element count (and a function better conveys the impression that this is a more complex task than a simple property access).  `List` is an `Iterable` and `Map` and `Array` probably have this to be consistent with `Iterable`.

Comment: @pixix4 Even if all iterables don't have a `size` property, couldn't they make getters for it to pretend they do?

Comment: A general guide is to only use getter if the function is "is cheap to calculate/O(1)" See [discuss.kotlinlang.org](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/default-getter-setter-versus-normal-function-in-kotlin/2304) or [blog.kotlin-academy.com](https://blog.kotlin-academy.com/kotlin-should-i-define-function-or-property-6786951da909). And on an simple `Iterable` the `count()` function is O(n) and therefor more complex to compute

Answer (score 1):

`size` and `count()` come from different interfaces. `size` is defined on `kotlin.collections.Collection`, which `List` and `Set` both implement:

```
public interface Collection<out E> : Iterable<E> {
    // Query Operations
    /**
     * Returns the size of the collection.
     */
    public val size: Int

    ...
```

while `count()` is an extension method defined on `kotlin.collections.Iterable` (which `Collection` inherits from):

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this collection.
 */
public fun <T> Iterable<T>.count(): Int {
    if (this is Collection) return size
    var count = 0
    for (element in this) checkCountOverflow(++count)
    return count
}
```

So merely inheriting from `Iterable` gives `Collection`s, including `List`s and `Set`s, a `count()` method automatically. And we definitely want `Collection` to inherit from `Iterable` so that we can pass a `Collection` to a method that will accept any `Iterable`. Then, finally, `Map` (which is not a `Collection`) gets both the `size` property and the `count()` method too for the sake consistency with `List` and `Set`.

Technically I guess that already answers the question of why collections have the `count()` method, but it is not yet a satisfying explanation because it invites a followup question: why do `Collection`s have the `size` property, then? Why didn't the standard library developers simply not bother adding `size` and instead have us call `count()` on `Collection`s?

The implementation of `count()`, quoted above, shows us the answer to *that* question: `size` is a performance optimisation. When called on a non-`Collection` `Iterable` of *n* elements, `count()` has *O(n)* time complexity, because it loops over all the elements in the iterable. When called on a `Collection`, it should have *O(1)* time complexity because it simply defers to the `size` property (which will hopefully be *O(1)* to evaluate!).

Next we might ask: could this optimisation have been achieved in some other way? Instead of complicating the API with an additional property, couldn't the standard library developers have simply had all the `Collection`s they implemented provide their own `count()` member function, with *O(1)* time complexity?

Nope. Because [extensions are resolved statically](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/extensions.html#extensions-are-resolved-statically) - so if you didn't have `size`, and instead had *O(1)* implementations of `count()` provided on `List`, `Map`, `Set`, and so on, then those *O(1)* implementations wouldn't get used when you passed a `List` or `Map` or `Set` to a function that takes an arbitrary `Iterable` as an argument and calls its `count()` method; instead, the call would be statically resolved to the *O(n)* extension method.

Having `size` and `count()` both exist is thus the only way to be able to make `count()` available on all `Iterable`s but also have it be *O(1)* for `Collection`s.

As a final note, if you were wondering why `count()` is a method and `size` is a property, the [Coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#functions-vs-properties) offer a clue:

> Functions vs properties
> In some cases functions with no arguments might be interchangeable with read-only properties. Although the semantics are similar, there are some stylistic conventions on when to prefer one to another.
>
> **Prefer a property over a function when the underlying algorithm:**
>
> - does not throw
> - **is cheap to calculate (or cached on the first run)**
> - returns the same result over invocations if the object state hasn't changed

(bolding mine). Since `count()` is (potentially) expensive to calculate but `size` is cheap, it follows that `count()` should be made a method and `size` a property - which is indeed what the standard library developers did.